# How do I "convert" the Unix Command Line arguments into a URL?

Tags: xml, perl, shell, rest, unix

So I am trying to figure out how to get an XML document from the REST Api of the Pfam Protein Sequence search service to build a Java application. Unfortunately all their documentation assumes you will be using Unix command line or scripting languages such as Perl. Basically, what I want to do is "convert" the following Unix command line argument into a url that I can type into the web browser to retrieve an xml document:

```
shell% curl -LH 'Expect:' -F seq=abhsghdsgsbsfkgajsdhsjsjsjdhsjshdj -F output=xml 'http://pfam.xfam.org/search/sequence'
```

Here is the link to the API documentation(http://pfam.xfam.org/help#tabview=tab10).
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you link to actually *does* explain this right from the start; but I suppose the authors could be clearer on how to convert between GET and POST requests for readers who are not well versed with HTTP.

```
http://pfam.xfam.org/search/sequence?seq=abhsghdsgsbsfkgajsdhsjsjsjdhsjshdj&output=xml
```

Comment: This link works except it is not formatted in XML...would you happen to know why ?

Comment: Nope, the `&output=xml` parameter looks like it should take care of it. Are you sure you are viewing it correctly (view source, examine HTTP headers)?

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided include the **reason** why it isn't currently with typycal browser-way:

> Running a search is a two step process:
>
> - submit the search sequence and specify search parameters
> - retrieve search results in XML format
>
> The reason for separating the operation into two steps rather than
>   performing a search in a single operation is that the time taken to
>   perform a sequence search will vary according to the length of the
>   sequence searched. **Most web clients, browsers or scripts, will simply
>   time-out if a response is not received within a short time period,
>   usually less than a minute. By submitting a search, waiting and then
>   retrieving results as a separate operation, we avoid the risk of a
>   client reaching a time-out before the results are returned.**

Answer (score 1):

Walk through the params on the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

- -LH 'Expect', looks like it send an Expect header.  Put that in your request header.
- -F key=value, these are form values that go in the body of a post.  Put them there.

Now that you have the requirements, go write some perl!

Answer (score 1):

> "convert" the following Unix command line argument into a url that I can type into the web browser to retrieve an xml document

Unfortunately, with just the information here, you can't do that. This syntax

- Includes a custom `Expect:` header
- Specifies that the request should be a `POST`, with fields (`-F`) included in the request body.

Anything you enter directly into a browser will be a `GET` with no custom headers.

However, it *may* be that the service will also accept a `GET` with the parameters specified in the query:

```
http://pfam.xfam.org/search/sequence?output=xml&seq=abhsghdsgsbsfkgajsdhsjsjsjdhsjshdj'
```

Comment: The linked doco explains that the `Expect:` header is a workaround for `curl`. My understanding is that it shouldn't be necessary for interactive browsing.